# Check Armbian version on the command line

Tags: linux, armbian, lsb-release

I have an *Orangepi+2e* device with Armbian OS.

How can I check Armbian version?
I tried with these commands, but can not found Armbian type.

```
$ sudo lsb_release -a
```

Out:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

and

```
$ sudo uname -r
```

Out:

`Linux orangepiplus2e 3.4.113-sun8i #16 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jun 13 14:15:57 CEST 2017 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install lsb-core`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check the armbian version look at the contents of the version file :

```
cat /etc/armbian-release
```